# Solr CharFilterFactory makes analysis tool return empty results

Tags: solr

I have used a CharFilterFactory in my schema.xml for fileType text_general, so that queries for cafe and café return the same results. It works correctly. Here's the relevant part of my schema.xml:

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

...however, the analysis tool within the admin user interface of solr seems to suggest that the tokenizers and filters that come after the charfilterfactory aren't doing anything. That's because if I analyse text_general with any field values for index and query, after MCF (MappingCharFilter), the output for ST, SF and LCF are all empty (grrr - a screen dump would be useful here, but I'm not allowed to post one because my 'reputation' isn't high enough apparently). Is that expected behaviour? Could someone please explain that analysis tool output please?

Comment: Actually, the LowerCaseFilterFactory must be getting invoked, because a query for "title:cafe" returns a result for something that was indexed as "title:Cafe".

Comment: What do you mean by empty? As in, it doesn't change the term, or the term disappears completely?

Comment: This is a bug with 4.7.0 and fixed as of 4.7.1. See this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5800